# How to get the Camera Preview into a viedeo-Stream? (Kotlin/Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, video-streaming, android-camerax

I am trying to write a mobile webcam for android and have been using Kotlin. The problem I have is that I can't find a working way to stream the preview of the kammera to the associated C# program.

The question is, how do I get the Kammera preview into a useful stream format and how do I get it to a C# (Windows) program over the network, i.e. which protocol is suitable for this?

so far I have the following code, which is responsible for initialising the camera and displaying it in the activity

Camera Activity:

```
 private fun startCamera() {
        cameraManager = CameraManager(
            owner = this,
            context = applicationContext,
            viewPreview = binding.pvViewCamera,
            onSuccess = ::onSuccess,
            onError = ::onError
        )
        cameraManager.startCamera(onFrontCamera = false)
    }
```

Camera Manager:

```
private fun controlWhichCameraToDisplay(frontCamera: Boolean?): Int {
        lensFacing = when (frontCamera) {
            true -> CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
            else -> CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
        }
        return lensFacing
    }

    fun startCamera(onFrontCamera: Boolean?) {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            controlWhichCameraToDisplay(frontCamera = onFrontCamera)
            bindCameraUseCases()
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
    }

    private fun bindCameraUseCases() {
        cameraProvider?.let { cameraProvider ->
            val cameraSelector = getCameraSelector()
            val previewView = getPreviewUseCase()
            imageCapture = getImageCapture()
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()
            try {
                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    owner,
                    cameraSelector,
                    previewView,
                    imageCapture
                )
                camera?.cameraControl?.setLinearZoom(0.0f)
                previewView.setSurfaceProvider(viewPreview.surfaceProvider)

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed $exc")
            }
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Camera initialization failed.")
    }
```

activity_camera.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".view.webcam.CameraActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
            android:id="@+id/pv_view_camera"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/match_constraints"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/match_constraints"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingClass" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/inc_buttons"
            layout="@layout/include_buttons_camera"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/match_constraints"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_close"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_24"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_24"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/ultra_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_close"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

if necessary for replication
include_buttons_camera.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_background_buttons">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_camera_capture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_56"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_56"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_change_camera"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_flash_camera"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_change_camera"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_24"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_24"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_change_camera"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_camera_capture"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_camera_capture"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_camera_capture" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_flash_camera"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_24"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_24"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_flash"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_camera_capture"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_camera_capture"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_camera_capture" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```